# NodeJS: MongoDB not connecting in Node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My app in nodeJS refuses to connect to the database when I run it, I am using mongoose ODM to connect to the database. When I run the application I get the error below.

```
Server running at  port 8000

/Users/user/www/document-manager/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1065:14)
```

Below is the code which I run:

```
var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
dotenv = require('dotenv'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
router = require("./server/router");

//Initialize App
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Initialize database connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/dms");

router(app);

//Load Dotenv
dotenv.load();

//Set Port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//Run applicatino
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server running at  port " + port);
});
```

The application would run if I run `mongod` from the terminal separately. Is there a way to run my database server and my application server together?

Comment: Well if you are not running Mongod, how do you expect your application will connect to MongoDB server? regarding your second question, you can start MongoDB when your machine starts and this highly depends on what kind of OS are you running. You can also try gulp, but this is not an ideal solution.